# how to get status of a pod in kubernetes using go-client

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

I am trying to delete a pod in my kubernetes cluster, then check its status to see how long does it take for the pod to get down, and up again. I could not find any helpful example for the second part which is getting a specific pod status using go-client. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use Get function to get specific pod information (below examples are getting whole Status struct):

```
pod, _ := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("kubernetes").Get(pod.Name, metav1.GetOptions{})
fmt.Println(pod.Status)
```

Also, you can use List function to get all pods in the particular namespace and then range them:

```
pods, _ := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("kubernetes").List(metav1.ListOptions{FieldSelector: "metadata.name=kubernetes"})
for _, pod := range pods.Items {
    fmt.Println(pod.Name, pod.Status)
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, This solution is working perfectly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The status info is a sub-struct of the pod as a whole so you use the normal getter (clientset.CoreV1() etc) and then look in the `.Status` struct.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? "clientset.CoreV1().Pods(namespace).Get("podname", metav1.GetOptions{}).Status"